# How to re-seed database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am creating some web app using ASP.Net Framework Core and Entity Framework Core.

I have created local database using entity framework core, I have seeded data.
The issue is that I need to re-seed the data, I need to have data with current dates for testing purposes.

I have created model and seeding in OnModelCreating method and it works fine for creating and seeding new database.

In OnModelCreating method, I am using HasData for seeding:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(PatientMockDB.Users);
    modelBuilder.Entity<VisitReview>().HasData(PatientMockDB.VisitReviews);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Visit>().HasData(PatientMockDB.AllVisits);
```

In PatientMockDB static class I have new data that I want to have in db.
OnModelCreating method is run whenever I run the app and want to take something from db.

When I delete db, delete migrations then EF will create db with new data, but I would prefer not to do it everyday, again.

How to force data update without deleting db?

Additional question, what is the best way to omit running OnModelCreating when database is already generated with up to date data or when on production?

Comment: seeding with efcore is part of migrations. if you modified that data outside of that, then update the model and create a new migration.

Comment: You can always change connection string to a new database to test.